# Create Teradata volatile table and select from table using isql

Tags: teradata, isql, ddl

I am trying to submit a two-statement SQL file as a batch job to the isql utility on a Linux machine.

The first statement defines a `VOLATILE TABLE` and the second statement is a `SELECT` statement against this table.

The Teradata server is hosted on a remote machine and I have successfully run `SELECT` statements to return result sets to my host.

Below is an example of the SQL file.

```
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE my_temp_table AS (
  SELECT 
    A.ID
    , MIN(A.DTE) AS FIRST_DATE
  FROM (
    SELECT
      X.ID
      , MIN(X.STRT_DTE) AS DTE
    FROM DATABASE0.TABLE_ABC AS X
    WHERE X.STRT_DTE BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE - 7) AND CURRENT_DATE
    GROUP BY X.ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      Y.ID
      , MIN(Y.STRT_DTE) AS DTE
    FROM DATABASE0.TABLE_XYZ AS Y
    WHERE Y.STRT_DTE BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE - 7) AND CURRENT_DATE
    GROUP BY Y.ID
  ) AS A
GROUP BY A.ID
)
WITH DATA
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
;
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM my_temp_table;
```

When I run the following command

```
cat my_two_statement_query.sql | isql -v -b -d',' mydsn myuid mypwd
```

I receive the following error

`[25000][Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Data definition not valid unless solitary.`

I am able to run these statements in Teradata client applications - Studio and SQL Assistant - with no issues.

UPDATE: I've included the contents of the odbc.ini file

```
[ODBC]
InstallDir=/path/to/installation/dir
Trace=0
TraceDll=/path/to/dll/odbctrac.so
TraceFile=/path/to/tracefile/odbc_trace.log
TraceAutoStop=0

[ODBC Data Sources]
proddsn=tdata.so

[proddsn]
Driver=/path/to/driver/tdata/so
Description=Teradata database
DBCName=TDPROD
LastUser=
Username=
Password=
Database=DATABASE0
DefaultDatabase=DATABASE0
NoScan=Yes
```

Comment: Seems like both statements were submitted as a single Multi Statement Request, which is not possible when DDL is included. Maybe the ODBC driver removed the white space, you might try the `NoScan=Yes` option in the ODBC.ini file

Comment: I second dnoeth in this. Another option you can try is to use a `GTT`  instead of a `Volatile` table.

Comment: @dnoeth: I added the `NoScan=Yes` option in the odbc.ini file (see above), but receive the same error.

Comment: @visakh: Unfortunately, I do not have CREATE TABLE access to the database ALL.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the last ; from your SQL file. I tried, it works for me.